# Swift iOS App how to display a UIView over a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, alert, tabbar

I have an iOS App with 3 ViewController, on my first ViewController if the user isn't logged I show a popUp that cover all the screen with a black UIView (opacity 50%, like a UIAlertController) and 2 buttons (register or log in).

The problem is, the tabBar is always over my UIView and i would like to display over the tabBar... (I can't juste hide the tabBar because of the opacity, i still want to see the tabBar under my black opacity 50% view.

I tried with layer's zPosition but that's doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Add the view in the AppDelegate's root window : (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate).window?.addSubview(yourview)

Comment: Where're you adding that transparent view? `tabbarController.view.addSubview(transparentView)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the view in window .

> AppDelegate.swift :

```
class func getDelegate() -> AppDelegate
    {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
```

> YourViewController.swift

```
    // set frame to full windows size 
    your_popup_view.frame = AppDelgate.getDelegate().window?.frame; 

    // add view on the top current window
    AppDelgate.getDelegate().window?.addSubview(your_popup_view)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct way to do it:

```
/* Add dialog to main window */
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate else { fatalError() }
guard let window = appDelegate.window else { fatalError() }
window?.addSubview(self)
window?.bringSubview(toFront: self)
window?.addSubview(**Your view**)
window?.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: `window` can't be `nil` after the guard so you need to remove all of those `?`.

Comment: anyway you need to force wrap it

Comment: No you don't. You have already safely unwrapped it with `guard`. It's not optional after the `guard` statement. You don't need `?` or `!` with `window` after the `guard`.

Comment: but if you run without **?** or **!** it gives errors. I just tried, just to be sure

Comment: To be clear, I'm taking about the last four lines in your answer. All the ones starting with `window?.xxx`. It just needs to be `window.xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class YourView: UIView {
    //setup your view...
}

protocol YourViewPresenter {
    func showYourView()
    func hideYourView()
}

extension YourViewPresenter where Self: UIViewController {
    func showYourView() {
        let yourView = YourView()
        view.addSubview(yourView)
        //after adding newly view, need to resize it
        yourView.fillSuperview()
    }

    func hideYourView() {
        (view.subviews.filter { $0 is PVInvitePopupView }).first?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func fillSuperView() {
        guard let superView = superview else { return }
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
    }
}
```

And then just conform you TabBarController to this extension:

```
extension UITabBarController: YourViewPresenter {}
//...
```

Then, you could call `showYourView()` somewhere in your viewController, like:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.showYourView()
}
```